# Check if an element of a 2D grid shares a diagonal, horizontal, or vertical with another element

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, traversal

I'm working on the n-queens problem and part of it is checking whether a queen is threatened by another to determine a good board state.

I have a 2D array filled with 0s, in this example a 4x4:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

I randomly populate each row with one queen, in this case represented by a 1:

```
0 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1
```

I need to check how many other pieces threaten a given piece. A queen is threatened if it shares a horizontal, diagonal, or vertical with another queen.

I'm not entirely sure how to traverse the array diagonally, however.

```
int checkThreats(vector<vector<int> > board, int r, int c) {
    int threats = 0;
    // checks vertical and horizontal
    for (int i = 0; i < board.size(); i++) {
        if (board[i][c] == 1 || board[r][i] == 1) {
            threats++;
        }
    }
    // it will count itself as a threat, so less one
    threats--;
    return threats;
}
```

This is the algorithm to check horizontally and vertically. Given a position on the board `r, c`, it checks how many queens exist in positions to the left, right, up, and down (in a cross + shape).

Take a co-ordinate `r, c` of `1, 0`, the positions checked are marked with an `x`, with an `o` if a threat exists:

```
x 0 1 0
o x x x
o 0 0 0
x 0 0 1
```

In this case, `threats == 1` as we don't count the original position.

My problem is trying to find pieces in an x shape, along the diagonals.

Comment: Just apply the offset to both indices. Check `board[r+i][c+i]` for some `i`, `[-min(r,c),+min(n-r,n-c)]` I think, or something like that. And `borad[r+i,r-i]` for the other axis.

Comment: Don’t you need to discard _two_ threats for `r!=c`?

Comment: @DavisHerring if I split the or within the if and instead had two ifs, yes.

Comment: @gator: Your `x`/`o` example will find the queen at (1,0) both when *i* is 0 (via `[r][i]`) and when *i* is 1 (via `[i][c]`).

Comment: Consider passing `board` as a `const &` to avoid unnecessary copies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through some trial and error, I was able to get an algorithm working. Here's the loops for traversing in all directions:

```
function check(arr, row, col) {
    for (i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {} // left/right can be iterated as normal
    for (i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {} // top/down can be the same
    // lower-right diagonal from (row, col)
    for (i = row+1, j = col+1; i < arr.size() && i < arr.size(); i++, j++) {}
    // upper-left diagonal from (row, col)
    for (i = row-1, j = col-1; i >= 0 && j >= 0; i--, j--) {}
    // lower-left diagonal from (row, col)
    for (i = row-1, j = col+1; i >= 0 && j < arr.size(); i--, j++) {}
    // upper-right diagonal from (row, col)
    for (i = row+1, j = col-1; i < arr.size() && j >= 0; i++, j--) {}
}
```

This only works for square arrays of course.

Answer (score 1):

The trick with diagonals is that they are of varying lengths (total and separately; consider that they comprise only 3 squares starting from an edge or corner of your board but 5 from the middle).  This irregularity makes them a bit harder to account for.

One strategy is to loop over (say) the rows, considering for each the 0 (if it’s the subject’s row), 1 (if one is off the board), or 2 squares that are on the diagonals in that row.  The column indices to check are just `c0+(r-r0)` and `c0-(r-r0)`.